# Python Tkinter listbox text edit in GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, listbox

Is there a way to edit a listbox item instead deleting it?

I am using a tkinter GUI with a listbox. Now my listbox could contain for example 10 items. If I would like to change the text of one item, is there a way to do it?

I know I can create a button to delete a single item, but is there any way to also jut edit an item?

Comment: Are you asking how the user can type into the listbox, or do you just want your code to be able to insert or replace something in the middle? The methods for inserting and deleting are documented.

Comment: I would like to enable the user to edit an alrady addd item (in the GUI not in the code)
Therefore I was hoping that there is something I could use to create a function, I could link to for example, an Edit button or so.

Comment: But do you want them to change it by typing in the listbox, or do you plan on having an entry widget outside of the listbox that they can type in?

Comment: ok got it - well bestwould be if they could just like double-click (or overwriting) the entry inside the listbox and edit there. Would like to avoid adding further entry fields to the GUI. It should just be a QoL feature to be able to edit an item inside list instead deleting it and re-add.

Comment: Whatever, you couldn't avoid deleting it and re-add

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The listbox doesn't support directly editing an item inside the listbox. You have to provide a mechanism for the user to enter data, and then you can replace just a single item in the listbox.

That being said, tkinter gives you all the tools you need to let the user double-click on an item and change it. Here's a quick hack of an example. In a nutshell, when you double-click, it will superimpose an entry widget over the item you clicked on, and when you press the return key it saves the item to the listbox.

```
import tkinter as tk

class EditableListbox(tk.Listbox):
    """A listbox where you can directly edit an item via double-click"""
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.edit_item = None
        self.bind("<Double-1>", self._start_edit)

    def _start_edit(self, event):
        index = self.index(f"@{event.x},{event.y}")
        self.start_edit(index)
        return "break"

    def start_edit(self, index):
        self.edit_item = index
        text = self.get(index)
        y0 = self.bbox(index)[1]
        entry = tk.Entry(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=1)
        entry.bind("<Return>", self.accept_edit)
        entry.bind("<Escape>", self.cancel_edit)

        entry.insert(0, text)
        entry.selection_from(0)
        entry.selection_to("end")
        entry.place(relx=0, y=y0, relwidth=1, width=-1)
        entry.focus_set()
        entry.grab_set()

    def cancel_edit(self, event):
        event.widget.destroy()

    def accept_edit(self, event):
        new_data = event.widget.get()
        self.delete(self.edit_item)
        self.insert(self.edit_item, new_data)
        event.widget.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
lb = EditableListbox(root)
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=lb.yview)
lb.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
lb.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

for i in range(100):
    lb.insert("end", f"Item #{i+1}")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This behaves very wierdly when you scroll the listbox.

Comment: @Danon: what do you mean by "weirdly"? If you are using the scrollwheel while the edit window is visible, then yes, it will behave weirdly. This was just to illustrate adding an entry widget over an item. For a production version you should either remove it when the user scrolls, or disable scrolling.

Comment: Exactly my point. Perhaps we should add the disabling of scroll into the example.

Comment: @Danon you can use vsb.pack_forget() after index in _start_edit and again pack the scrollbar after editing is accepted or cancelled. see the modified code in answer

Answer (score 1):

modified version fo code shared by @Bryan Oakley, this version removes the scrollbar when editing is started and place back the scrollbar after editing is cancelled or done

```
import tkinter as tk
class EditableListbox:
    def __init__(self):
        self.editItemIndex = None
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.lb = tk.Listbox(self.root)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.root, command=self.lb.yview)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.lb.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.lb.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        for i in range(100):
            self.lb.insert("end", f"Item #{i + 1}")
        self.lb.bind("<Double-1>", self.startEdit)

    def startEdit(self, event):
        index = self.lb.index(f"@{event.x},{event.y}")
        self.vsb.pack_forget()
        self._start_edit(index)
        return "break"

    def _start_edit(self, index):
        self.editItemIndex = index
        text = self.lb.get(index)
        y0 = self.lb.bbox(index)[1]
        entry = tk.Entry(self.root, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=1)
        entry.bind("<Return>", self.accept_edit)
        entry.bind("<Escape>", self.cancel_edit)
        entry.insert(0, text)
        entry.selection_from(0)
        entry.selection_to("end")
        entry.place(relx=0, y=y0, relwidth=1, width=-20)
        entry.focus_set()
        entry.grab_set()

    def cancel_edit(self, event):
        event.widget.destroy()
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")

    def accept_edit(self, event):
        new_data = event.widget.get()
        self.lb.delete(self.editItemIndex)
        self.lb.insert(self.editItemIndex, new_data)
        event.widget.destroy()
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")

    def runGUI(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    flc_app = EditableListbox()
    flc_app.runGUI()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant, when dynamically populating listbox items from events, with use of EditableListbox(). If the listbox item is outside the visible area bbox() looks for, it raises a NoneType error on self.bbox(index)[1]. This is due to the newly added item being outside the visible window.

The below simply checks if the item is visible and calls see(index) respectively. However, it will manipulate the original visible state of the Listbox items (in regards to vscroll).

#TODO: Incorporate bbox() state preservation and restore after.

```
class EditableListbox(tk.Listbox):
    """A listbox where you can directly edit an item via double-click
listbox-text-edit-in-gui """
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.edit_item = None
        self.bind("<Double-1>", self._start_edit)

    def _start_edit(self, event):
        index = self.index(f"@{event.x},{event.y}")
        self.start_edit(index)
        return "break"

    def start_edit(self, index, accept_func=None,cancel_func=None):
        if self.bbox(index) == None:
            self.see(index)

        self.edit_item = index
        text = self.get(index)
        y0 = self.bbox(index)[1]
        entry = tk.Entry(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=1)
        entry.bind("<Return>", self.accept_edit)
        entry.bind("<Escape>", self.cancel_edit)

        entry.insert(0, text)
        entry.selection_from(0)
        entry.selection_to("end")
        entry.place(relx=0, y=y0, relwidth=1, width=-1)
        entry.focus_set()
        entry.grab_set()

    def cancel_edit(self, event):
        event.widget.destroy()

    def accept_edit(self, event):
        new_data = event.widget.get()
        self.delete(self.edit_item)
        self.insert(self.edit_item, new_data)
        event.widget.destroy()
```